# Recorder for AutoIt 

Tags: script, recording, autoit

Does anyone know where to find the latest AutoIt recorder? The one [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autoit-recorder/) does not work. It does not find `RWSettings.alg` and I do not know what that is. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did was first download the official autoit installer and then enter the installation directory. There should be a folder named Extras. Inside this folder there should be another folder named Au3Record. This is the directory of the autoit recorder.

Comment: Thanks @TGS. We have a saying "The child is in the lap and the mother is looking for him". The `Au3Record` program was already there as I did not check the `Extra` folder

Comment: This answer is no longer correct; the recorder is no longer included in this directory for the full install of AutoIt.

Answer (score 3):

Autoit recorder has been removed from the main package as of v3.3.14.1, apparently because it was giving false positives from AV software according to this [autoit thread](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/176009-where-is-au3recordexe/).

It also mentions `https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.14.0.zip` as the the place to download the last version of autoit with the recorder. The thread also mentions the *actual* link may trigger off some AV software.

Comment: This should be the top answer, its the only one here that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **[SciTE](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/)** `SciTE4AutoIt3.exe` for alternate solution.

[image]

Comment: Menu entry to recorder not present in SciTE installed today Dec 11th, 2019.